# Leon v3 ise-prog-prom error: impact:2070

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I have the following error while executing the command ise-prog-prom to synthesize the vhdl on the platform :

```
error:impact:2070 There are only 0 devices on the chain. Position 1 does not exists.
```

I have tried to look online for some answers but I've had no luck so far.

Does anyone know where this bug come from and, even better, how to fix it ?

Here is the log I have :

```
$ make ise-prog-prom
promgen -x xcf32p xcf32p -u 0 leon3mp.bit -p mcs -w -o gr-pci-xc5v
Release 14.6 - Promgen P.68d (nt64)
Copyright (c) 1995-2013 Xilinx, Inc.  All rights reserved.
0x378d00 (3640576) bytes loaded up from 0x0
Using user-specified prom size of 8192K
Writing file "gr-pci-xc5v_0.mcs".
Writing file "gr-pci-xc5v_0.prm".
WARNING:Bitstream:59 - The address range 0040:0000 - 0080:0000 for the PROM
   gr-pci-xc5v_1.mcs does not contain any bitstream data.  No file will be
   written for this PROM.
Writing file "gr-pci-xc5v_0.cfi".
cp leon3mp.bit gr-pci-xc5v.bit
cp leon3mp.msk gr-pci-xc5v.msk
impact -batch ../../boards/gr-pci-xc5v/prom.cmd
Release 14.6 - iMPACT P.68d (nt64)
Copyright (c) 1995-2013 Xilinx, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Preference Table
Name                 Setting
StartupClock         Auto_Correction
AutoSignature        False
KeepSVF              False
ConcurrentMode       False
UseHighz             False
ConfigOnFailure      Stop
UserLevel            Novice
MessageLevel         Detailed
svfUseTime           false
SpiByteSwap          Auto_Correction
AutoInfer            false
SvfPlayDisplayComments false
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Plugin Version: 2.4.4
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: found 1 device(s).
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: opening device: "JtagHs1", SN:210205333142
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: User Name: JtagHs1
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Product Name: Digilent JTAG-HS1
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Serial Number: 210205333142
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Product ID: 30700150
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Firmware Version: 0108
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: JTAG Port Number: 0
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: JTAG Clock Frequency: 10000000 Hz
Identifying chain contents...'0': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'1': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'2': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'3': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'4': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'5': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'6': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'7': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'8': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'9': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'10': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'11': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'12': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'13': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'14': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'15': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'16': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'17': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'18': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'19': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'20': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'21': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'22': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'23': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'24': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'25': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'26': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'27': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'28': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'29': : Manufacturer's ID = Unknown
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device UNKNOWN successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:iMPACT - iMPACT quit the Identify Chain because it detects there are
   at least 30 'UNKNOWN' type devices on the chain.
   Please check the hardware settings and retry!
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Elapsed time =      2 sec.
Elapsed time =      0 sec.
ERROR:iMPACT:2070 - There are only 0 devices on the chain. Position 1 does not
   exist.
make: *** [ise-prog-prom] Error 1
```

Comment: `ise-prog-prom` cannot be used to synthesise, only to download after synthesis, translate, map and PAR. If you're really trying to use IMPACT here, check the JTAG adaptor is plugged in, and it and the board are correctly powered.

Comment: Hi Brian and sorry for the delay of replying, I was not in the office.

Comment: You are right, I meant downloading, not synthesis (english is not my mother tong, I struggle sometimes:). The JTAG adaptor is plugged in and the board is powered. 
I have actually successfully managed dowloading a softcore leon 3 last week. The only thing I have changed was a component, I did not touch the code of the core. I have reverted to a version of the component that was working but I still have the error message.
I am going to post the log just in case. Meanwhile, I am going to check the JTAG, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is generated because your programmer cannot find any JTAG devices on the chain to program. It's not connected to the device you're trying to program.

How to troubleshoot that specifically is hard to say, I would suggest for starters that you make sure the programmer is connected correctly to the board.  If you're using the JTAG Platform Cable II like I do, this means the indicator LED on the programmer will be lit up green (not yellow).  Then I would refresh the JTAG chain.  If the solution isn't immediately obvious, see if [this page](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/isehelp/pim_r_common_issues_and_debug_solutions.htm) is helpful to you at all.

Comment: Hi Ian, I'm going to look at it straight away, thank you so much for this information.

Comment: Ian, the problem came from the JTAG indeed. One of the pin (vdd, I believe) was broken and after fixing it, everything is back to normal. Thank you again for your help.